# Running gdb with a source file

Tags: linux, gdb

I have a Linux executable file and I can run it on command line, but at first, I should use

```
source ./somefile
```

If I don't `source` it, the executable crashed. I also, can run the file under dbg. But I need to `source somefile` in gdb also. I mean, I already make `source ./somefile` then run the gdb and run the executable in it, the executable crashed like without using source ./somefile.

By the way, ***somefile*** that I should `source` contains some EXPORT=bla bla definitions.

Executable is an embedded qt software, running on imx6 board. Sourcing somefile makes some definition about qt libraries. The crash message when I run the executable without sourcing somefile and when sourcing it and then run in gdb is exactly the same. So I think that after source somefile, if I run the executable in gdb, it seems gdb doesn't know libraries' path. May be a way to source a file for gdb.

Comment: You need to give in your question the content of `somefile`; BTW the Linux debugger is `gdb` (not *`dbg`*). And you should also tell more about your executable. BTW, it should not crash (but give some meaningful message) in such case. Also, do you have the source code of your executable? Are you able to build it yourself? How?? Please **edit your question** to improve it a lot. If possible, provide some [MCVE] reproducing your issue

Comment: In its current state, your question is unclear and too broad. You badly need to improve it a lotr.

Comment: So it crahes if either the `source` command isn't used or it's run under gdb. Does it crash the exact same way both times? Sometimes programs have multiple bugs.

Comment: What is your question? Are you asking how to set environment variables inside gdb?

Comment: ks1322 yes i think my problem is that. Or simply to run source command for gdb.

Comment: Mark Plotnick, I edited the question. It crashes without source command or with source command but under gdb, the same way both time.

Comment: Even with the edit, the question stays unclear. You really need to show the sourced file in your question.

Comment: Does the shell script `./somefile` contain only shell variable assignments and `export` commands, or are there `alias` commands or function definitions, too?

Answer (score 2):

I guess you are asking how to set environment variables inside gdb.

You should use `set environment`, see builtin help:

```
(gdb) help set environment 
Set environment variable value to give the program.
Arguments are VAR VALUE where VAR is variable name and VALUE is value.
VALUES of environment variables are uninterpreted strings.
This does not affect the program until the next "run" command.
(gdb)
```

You will have to take `VAR` and `VALUE` from `./somefile`. You can't simply `source` it in gdb prompt because it is shell script, not gdb script.

Answer (score 0):

You might run your `source` command, and later, in the *same* shell (e.g. same terminal window), run `gdb` to debug your program. The environment variables setup by your `source` builtin command are valid for not only the `gdb` process, but also the debugged process.

Read more about [Debugging with GDB](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/).

Comment: thanks for the answer but I have already tried what you said.

Comment: Then you need to improve your question by editing it.